# MUI X Data Grid multivalue cell filtering

Tags: material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I'm using DataGrid component to display my data and in one column I have multiple values. To display them I'm using `renderCell` and displaing it as multiple `Chip` components. But right now no idea how to filter this column.
My data format

```
"categories":{"8":"category1","14":"category2"}
```

Chip code

```
<Chip key={key} label={categories[key]} size="small"/>
```

Right now it is not filtering this column on free type text with using category id or its label